# Unbound Local Error: referenced before assignment?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import turtle

ben = turtle.Turtle()
W = 1
ben.speed(10.5)
ben.width(5)
#X = 0
O = 0



if GRIDDONE == True: #inside lines
    ben.speed(10.5)
    ben.forward(100)
    ben.right(90)
    ben.forward(300)
    ben.left(90)
    ben.forward(100)
    ben.left(90)
    ben.forward(300)
    ben.right(90)
    ben.forward(100)
    ben.right(90)
    ben.forward(100)
    ben.right(90)
    ben.forward(300)
    ben.left(90)
    ben.forward(100)
    ben.left(90)
    ben.forward(300)

ben.pu()
ben.forward(500)

X = turtle.Turtle()
O = turtle.Turtle()
X.pu()
O.pu()

X.forward(300)
X.right(90)
O.forward(300)
O.right(90)

X.color("Blue")
X.color()
O.color("Red")
O.color()
X.width(2)
O.width(2)
#X.speed(100)
#O.speed(100)

SQ1 = False


StartX = '300'
StaryY = '0'


def playX():
    P1 = input('Can player X please choose their square')

    if (P1) == ('1'):
        if (SQ1) == False:
            X.right(90)
            X.forward(300) #change this
            X.left(90)
            X.left(45)
            X.pd()
            X.forward(140)
            X.pu()
            X.left(135)
            X.forward(100)
            X.left(135)
            X.pd()
            X.forward(140)
            X.pu()
            X.setx(300)
            X.sety(0)
            X.left(45)
            SQ1 = True




def playO():
    P1 = input('Can player O please choose their square')

    if P1 == ('1'):
        if SQ1 == False:
            O.right(90)
            O.forward(300) #change this
            O.left(90)
            O.forward(50)
            O.left(90)
            O.forward(10)
            O.left(90)
            O.pd()
            O.circle(-40)
            O.pu()
            O.setx(300)
            O.sety(0)
            O.left(180)
            SQ1 = True


playO()
#playX()
```

THIS IS my code and i need to create a feature that doesn't allow the turtle to draw under the same 'if' function twice but i get the error in the title. The error is as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\benna\Downloads\2.py", line 314, in 
playO()
File "C:\Users\benna\Downloads\2.py", line 297, in playO
if SQ1 == False:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'SQ1' referenced before assignment

i think its because the variable can't be edited whilst in use in the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to `SQ1` being declared in the global space and then being accessed inside your `play0()` function.

You can fix this error by using the keyword `global`.  Add a line inside your `play0()` function that specifies `SQ1` is global as shown below (see line 2):

```
def playO():
    global SQ1

    P1 = input('Can player O please choose their square')

    if P1 == ('1'):
        if SQ1 == False:
```

Further improvements:

I would suggest following the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for your variable names and to help improve the readability of the code.