# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Take_photo' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter

## i want to make a hand gesture that can take a photo.. so after making the hand gesture there will be a countdown time to take the photo but I am still a beginner in python so I don't understand about the error..

[code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEhhy.png)

[code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKB9s.png)

[code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zNIv.png)

[code 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukxbZ.png)

[code 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbeRY.png)

Comment: Post code and errors as text, not images.

Comment: Look for conditions where setting Take_photo may be skipped. There's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have made a change to the variable `Take_photo` in the function. That's why there is the error here.

You can just simply add `global Take_photo` and it should work.

#### Your function should be:

```
def btn_clicked():
    global Take_photo
    #your code
```

You might want to have a look at this answer for more detail
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50766668/17990633

Hope it works, have a nice day!

Comment: I've tried it but the result is different from what I expected, the countdown time stops and doesn't take photos

Comment: Can you please give the full code, especially the code inside that function? I cannot know your situation yet.

Comment: Also, if the result is different from what you've expected, there might be some problem in your code algorithm, you may try to scan the whole code again to find the problem.

Comment: i already change the photo.. actualy i am new using and asking in this stackoverflow..so when i  tried to copy my code so many warn that i get

Comment: actually I have tried this program before and it worked but because I wanted to make the GUI I encountered this error

Comment: i already solved it.. thx